# JavaScript SQLite transaction rollback

Tags: javascript, sqlite, transactions

I am developing some DB actions for my Phonegap app. I am testing the transaction functionality of SQLite and there is one point, that I don't understand.

Here the example in one transaction:

```
dbObj.dbConnection.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO foo (id, text) VALUES (?, ?)', [6,"aaalabala6"], function(tx, results) {
         document.write("make insert<br>");
      }, function (tx, err){
        alert(err.message);
      });

    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE foo (id unique, text)', [], function(tx, results) {

    }, function (tx, err){
        console.log(err.message); // here an error - table already exists
    });

    tx.executeSql('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO foo (id, text) VALUES (?, ?)', [7,"aaalabala7"], function(tx, results) {
         document.write("make insert<br>");
      }, function (tx, err){
        alert(err.message);
      });
});
```

The middle SQL query is throwing an error (could not prepare statement (1 table foo already exists)), because the table "foo" already exists. The question is, why is the transaction not doing rollback? Can I somehow force the transaction rollback on error?

Do I have an error in my statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To rollback the whole transaction, your error-handling callback function should return `true`, as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH3-SW3):

> **Per-Query Error Callbacks**
>
> The per-query error-handling callback is
>   rather straightforward. If the callback returns true, the entire
>   transaction is rolled back. If the callback returns false, the
>   transaction continues as if nothing had gone wrong.
>
> Thus, if you are executing a query that is optional — if a failure of
>   that particular query should not cause the transaction to fail—you
>   should pass in a callback that returns false. If a failure of the
>   query should cause the entire transaction to fail, you should pass in
>   a callback that returns true.

Right now error handlers return `undefined` (as no explicit `return` statement is there), so only the affected action is skipped.